# I would be grateful if anyone can translate/identify the artist of this Chinese "Farmers' Art" painting

Tags: translation, meaning, names

The attached image is of a painting of the genre known as Chinese Farmers' / Chinese Peasants'/ or Chinese 'naive" paintings. But I cannot de-code the signature and seal, so would be most grateful if anyone can[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80L7M.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Let's break it down:

盼春：Looking forward to Spring

户县：Hu County

张青义：Qingyi Zhang

作: Painted By

---

**Title of the painting is:**

盼春：Looking forward to Spring

**Full translation is:**

户县张青义作：Painting by Qingyi Zhang from Hu County

**Seal:**

The right side translate to 青义，which is the painter's Firstname, not sure about the left side. The previous answer says it's 画印, which translate to Seal, so the Seal translate to: Qingyi Seal

---

Found something about the painter, and one of the painting has the title 盼春 as well:

[张青义户县农民作品画欣赏](http://www.360doc.com/content/18/0507/17/412944_751919621.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

Title 户县张青义作 盼春 Seal 青义画印
Here is the Baidu baike link to [户县农民画](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%88%B7%E5%8E%BF%E5%86%9C%E6%B0%91%E7%94%BB)